# How to use writeCell in mpdf library

Tags: yii2, mpdf

I am using the Mpdf library, all good, however there is something that does not work well. When I use the writeCell () function, it does not paint anything. My code is as follows:

```
$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->SetXY(107,30);
$mpdf->WriteCell( 10,30, 'member_code','','','R');
```

I need Some help

Answer (score 1):

When not using WriteHTML when generating the PDF, you have to create a page to write on with `AddPage` method.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->AddPage();

$mpdf->SetXY(107, 30);
$mpdf->WriteCell(10, 30, 'member_code', '', '', 'R');
```

Comment: No it's not the answer. By putting $mpdf->AddPage()  , the problem persist, even more add a blank page.

Comment: Curious, I tested it ad it works. What is your mPDF version?

Answer (score 0):

before using WriteCell(), need using  WriteHTML() once first.
see https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/1013